# Code works in Pycharm but not in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I have written a piece of code in Pycharm which seems to execute flawlessly, but as soon as I put the code in Jupyter notebook I get the message : 
[image: IndexError: list index out of range] (Image)

Here is what my code looks like (Python) :

```
def parse_planets_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        inputm = f.readlines()
        method = inputm[0].split(",")
        del inputm[0]
        del method[0]
        data = {}
        for row in inputm:
            row = (row.strip()).split(",")
            if row[0] not in data:
                data[row[0]] = {h.strip(): [] for h in method}
            for i, h in enumerate(method):
                h = h.strip()
                data[row[0]][h].append(float(row[i + 1]) if row[i + 1] else row[i + 1])
        return data


fname = "exoplanets.csv"
print(parse_planets_file(fname))
```

The exact code in Pycharm executes and I get no error. Anyone able to help me out?

Comment: Its attached as a image

Comment: Do a `print(inputm)` after the `readlines()` func - do you get the data?

Comment: Also, don't forget t run the cell that contains the function after you have made changes.

Comment: No, just an empty bracket followed by same traceback error

Comment: try: `open(fname, 'r')`

Comment: I'm still getting the same traceback error.

Comment: I think this may be an issue with trying to read the file through notebook - Appologies because I use JupyterHub which has an import

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972225/how-to-open-local-file-on-jupyter) help?

Comment: Ensure Python versions are same on both environments. The string that holds the path to the file might be interpreted differently on python2 vs python3. Check the file descriptor if it's what you expect https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object

Comment: Thanks all for the help, turns out it was something wrong within Jupyter as when I deleted and reuploaded the file the problem seemed to fix itself. Thanks again!