# Unable to set working directory for Jupyter Lab on Mac

Tags: python, macos, directory, jupyter

I'm working with Jupyter Lab on a Mac.  I've been trying to change the working directory in a .ipynb script via `os.chdir()`, so I can use the code to iteratively process multiple files in the working directory.

Eventually, I would like to use `os.listdir()` to iterate through the files in the directory.

My laptop files show up properly in the menu on the left, but for some reason, the following code won't work:

```
# set working directory
os.chdir('C:/Users/glonati/Documents/2019-_UNB SJ/drone/programs_code/python')
path = os.getcwd()
```

It produces the error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/glonati/Documents/2019-_UNB SJ/drone/programs_code/python'`

I've quadruple checked the path names and tried all combinations of '', "", as well as , \, and /.

I read that I should try modifying the jupyter config file.  But when I download the file (via `jupyter notebook --generate-config`), the only lines in the file are:

```
c.NotebookApp.allow_credentials = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8889
c.NotebookApp.password_required = True
```

There is no line for `c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ''`.

Unsure why I'm having so much trouble with this.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46972225/how-to-open-local-file-on-jupyter

Comment: Thank you @AndrewRyan!  The suggestion from Reblochon Masque worked :)